# Computer Won't Boot Anymore - 16.04

Tags: boot, mount, 16.04

My computer (Ubuntu 16.04) doesn't boot anymore with an error message that makes no sense to me:

`EXT4-fs (dm-2): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities`

This makes no sense to me because it was working yesterday and I didn't intentionally change anything.  I turned it off last night and now it won't boot today.  There were a number of system updates that I installed, that's the only significant thing I can think of.  So the drive has always been mountable as ext3 because it is an ext3.  Why is it suggesting it's not an ext3 drive now?

The entry in my /etc/fstab corresponding to this is:

`/dev/mapper/isw_dhciiffhhj_Groovy2 /var ext3 defaults,relatime 0 2`

Other mounts seem to have mounted successfully, but they are not ext3 mounts either.  I would surmise in a recent update something broke ext3 and that has impacted my `/var/` mount.

**Kernel**: 4.4.0-28-generic

**UPDATE:** If I manually change the fstype from ext3 to ext4 in `/etc/fstab` then it mounts and the computer continues to boot, but I don't understand why this drive didn't fail to mount before.  If ext3 was invalid I should have run into this issue several months ago.  Could anybody shed some light on why this may have failed?  It looks like as part of my recent updates installed overnight there was a kernel update.

Comment: Have you tried booting from a LiveCD or USB and running `fsck` on the partition?